# Convert the integral on the ball to unit sphere

Tags: calculus

I want to convert the integral defined  below on $|y|=r$  in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to unit sphere. I changed variable $y=rw$

\begin{align}
\int_{|y|=r} \Phi(x,y)ds(y)= \int_{|w|=1} \Phi(x,rw)ds(rw)
\end{align}
I want to find the jacobian . I dont undestand what $ds(rw )$ means. can we write it in detail ? I mean as meaning of $ds(rw)$.
Thank you for your help.